# Flutter display featured image from wordpress api

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I'm trying to display the featured image from a Wordpress api using the following code:

home.dart:

```
class _PostTileState extends State<PostTile> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        child: Column(children: [
      FutureBuilder(
        future: fetchWpPostImageUrl(widget.href),
        builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            return Image.network(snapshot.data["guid"]["rendered"]);
          }

          return CircularProgressIndicator();
        },
      ),
      Text(widget.title),
      Text(widget.desc)
        ]));
  }
}
```

wp-api.dart:

```
Future fetchWpPostImageUrl(href) async {
  final response =
    await http.get(href, headers: {"Accept": "application/json"});

  var convertedDatatoJson = jsonDecode(response.body);
  return convertedDatatoJson;
}
```

The code executes at the CircularProgressIndicator but does not display the image despite the map being correct.

Comment: Did you try to print response or image url response ?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue:

```
Future fetchWpPostImageUrl(href) async {
  final response =
      await http.get(Uri.parse(href), headers: {"Accept": "application/json"});
  var convertedDataJson = jsonDecode(response.body);
  return convertedDataJson;
}
```